# Which actions get counted towards your APM in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have keybinds that, for example, will move my screen to a set location. If my keybind is 2 buttons, will I gain +2 actions whenever I press it?

What about consecutive actions?

Overall, what actions get counted towards your APM in Starcraft 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every click and command counts as an action. Pressing multiple buttons for one command (e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to add units to group 1) counts as one action, so your keybind will count as one action.

Consecutive actions are also all counted by APM. However, EPM (effective APM) is calculated differently and removes some redundant actions. Doing the same thing repeatedly or too quickly will not count towards EPM, but exactly how Blizzard calculates EPM is unknown.

Comment: At the end of the score screen, is the APM shown the EPM?

Comment: I can check for sure later, but I'm pretty certain it's APM. It definitely says which on the score screen.